# Ordering some functions without losing continuity

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

Let's consider the set $\mathbb R^{n}/S_n$, i.e. the quotient of $\mathbb R^{n}$  modulo permutations. An element $a \in \mathbb R^{n}/S_n$ is simply a $n$-tuple of real numbers (the order does not matter).

This set has clearly the quotient topology and it is metrizable, being the distance the so called "*optimal matching distance*": 
$$
d(a,b)= \min_{\sigma \in S_n} \max_{1\le j \le n} \vert a_j-b_{\sigma(j)}\vert
$$ 
for $a=\{a_1, \ldots , a_n\}$ and $b = \{b_1, \ldots , b_n\}$.

I know the following result holds true:

**Theorem.** Let $O:\mathbb R^{n}/S_n \to \mathbb R^{n}$ the map that "orders" the numbers of the n-tuple, i.e. 
$$
\{a_1, \ldots , a_n\} \mapsto O(\{a_1, \ldots , a_n\}):=(\hat{a}_{1}, \ldots , \hat{a}_n)
$$
where $\hat{a}_{1}\le \ldots \le \hat{a}_n$. Then $O$ it's Lipschitz continuous, i.e.
$$
\max_{i}\vert \hat{a}_i - \hat{b}_i\vert \le d(a,b)
$$

---

Now take $n$ continuous functions, $\phi_j \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb {R}$. I would like to prove that there is a way to relabel the functions (without losing continuity) s.t.
$$
\phi_1(t) \le \phi_2(t) \le \ldots \le \phi_n(t) \le \phi_1(t) + 2\pi , \quad \forall t \in [0,1] 
$$

The functions $\phi_j$ have also this important property: for every $t \in [0,1]$
$$
\phi_j(t) = \phi_j(t)+2k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb Z
$$ 
(indeed, they represent angular coordinates, therefore I can translate them up and down by multiple of $2\pi$).
I would like to prove this property (but I am still not sure about the statement):

> Given $n$ continuous functions $\phi_j \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$
>   ($j=1, \ldots n$) then there exist other $n$ continuous functions
>   $\vartheta_j \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ s.t.
>
> 1. $$ \vartheta_1(t) \le \vartheta_2(t) \le \ldots \le \vartheta_n(t) \le  \vartheta_1(t)+2\pi \qquad \forall t \in [0,1] $$
> 2. for every $t \in [0,1]$, for every $i=1, \ldots , N$ there exists $j \in \{1,\ldots , n\}$ and $k \in \mathbb Z$ s.t.  $$ \vartheta_i(t)=\phi_j(t)+2k\pi $$ ($j,z$ depend on $t$).

Do you think this last statemente is true? To prove it, I would like to use the theorem above: for every $\bar{t} \in [0,1]$ I consider the $(n+1)$-tuple given by $\{\phi_1(\bar{t}), \phi_2(\bar{t}), \ldots \le \phi_n(\bar{t}), \phi_1(\bar{t}) + 2\pi\}$: can I apply the theorem to conclude?

**Example.**

Consider the two functions $\phi_1(t)=-t$ and $\phi_2(t)=t$, defined on $[0,2\pi]$ (it's clearly the same of $[0,1]$, but it simplifies the calculations). Initially, there's no relationship between them. But if you put 
$$
\vartheta_1 = \begin{cases}
-t \qquad t \in [0,\pi] \\
t-2\pi \qquad t \in [\pi, 2\pi]
\end{cases}
$$ 
and
$$
\vartheta_2 = \begin{cases}
t \qquad t \in [0,\pi] \\
-t+2\pi \qquad t \in [\pi,2\pi ]
\end{cases}
$$ 
then you can write $\vartheta_1(t) \le \vartheta_2(t) \le \vartheta_1(t)+2\pi$ for every $t \in [0,1]$. This is exacly what I want.

---

If you know any reference (book, article etc) which deals with this, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If the order does not matter than you simply have a multiset, not a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear enough. What do you mean by "relabeling" the functions? If you are given $\phi_1(t)=t$ and $\phi_2(t)=1-t$, you may well decide to change the label (indices) and write instead $\phi_2(t)=t$ and $\phi_1(t)=1-t$. Of course, the functions don't become discontinuous from being called by another name. On the other hand, you don't get the ordering you want because for some values of $t$ the inequality between $\phi_1(t)$ and $\phi_2(t)$ goes one way, for others the opposite way.

Perhaps you want to introduce different functions: $\bar \phi_1(t)=\min(\phi_1(t),\phi_2(t))$ and $\bar \phi_2(t)=\max(\phi_1(t),\phi_2(t))$. This achieves $\bar\phi(t)\le \bar\phi_2(t)$ for all $t$. The functions are still continuous: the maximum of two continuous functions is continuous, and the minimum too. However, there is no reason to expect $\bar\phi_2(t)\le \bar\phi_1(t)+2\pi$ unless you have some information about your functions that involves $2\pi$. You stated no such assumptions in your post.

When $n>2$, the definition of $\bar \phi_k$ becomes a bit clumsy, but still works: $\bar \phi_k(t)=\min\limits_{I}\max\limits_{j\in I}\phi_j(t)$ where the minimum is taken over all sets $I\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ of cardinality $k$.

An excellent current reference on maps into spaces like $\mathbb R^{n}/S_n$ is [Q-valued functions revisited](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0060) by De Lellis and Spadaro. Actually, their work emphasizes the more difficult issues involving $\mathbb R^{nQ}/S_{Q}$, i.e., the space of unordered $Q$-tuples of $n$-dimensional vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. I have just added some additional information and I've edited my post. Hope now the question is clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Romeo Counterexample: $\phi_1(t)=0$ for all $t$ and $\phi_2(t)=100t$. Now $\vartheta_1$ must be constant, and there is no way to choose $\vartheta_2$ continuously: it would be the same as continuous choice of argument on the entire circle.

Comment: You are right. What if we add that $\phi_j$ are not constant but we require only that $\phi_j(0)=0$ for every $j=1, \ldots , N$? Thanks again.

Comment: @Romeo Does not make a difference: take $\phi_1(t)=t/100$ and $\phi_2(t)=100t$.

Comment: Consider for sake of simplicity $\phi_1(t)=t$ and $\phi_2(t)=2t$. Then for $t \in [0,2\pi]$ it's ok, we set $\vartheta_1=\phi_1$ and $\vartheta_2=\phi_2$. For $t \ge 2\pi$ just define $\vartheta_1 = 2t-2\pi$ and $\vartheta_2 = t+2\pi$ (clearly this works until $t=4\pi$, then we relabel again). Is this so different from taking $100t$ and $t/100$ (apart from calculations, I mean)?

Comment: @Romeo Sorry, I did not notice the difference between $i$ and $j$ in your item 2 above. This would not have happened if you stated item 2 precisely, attaching quantifiers to $i$ and $j$. For every $i$ there exists $j$? Or for every $j$ there exists $i$? Or something else?

Comment: I think it's for every $i$ there exists $j$: anyway, I've edited again the post. I apologize for being imprecise and I thank you again for your help.